# how to install cuda 10.2 or cuda 11 for ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nvidia, cuda

I want to install cuda 10.2 or cuda 11.1 on my machine with ubuntu 16.04.

My aim is to run my pytorch code on the GPU and it requires these cuda versions.

Currently, I have a cuda 8 which I checked using:

```
~$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Jan_10_13:22:03_CST_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.61
```

There are many guides out there but none of them mention clearly about 16.04 version. Please recommend a way that works.

Thank you

Comment: 16.04 went "End of life" these days, you should upgrade to a supported Ubuntu release as soon as possible.

Comment: okay, but I found this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu) where there is a way to to get cuda 11 in ubuntu 16.04 . Is it any good?

Comment: No, not good. You should upgrade to a supported Ubuntu release as soon as possible.